# Insert static HTML to AEM page

Tags: html, aem

I have a HTMl file and AEM template with header, footer and blank content.

I want to create an AEM page based on the template and also fill the blank content with the HTMl file. I know the PageManager API can create a page using certain template, and the JcrUtils API can add node (textNode, imageNode) when creating a page. But how can I insert the static HTML file as a component of an AEM page?

Comment: Just provide an input where the user could paste the markup, and read the property in HTL.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few ways you can achieve this -

- Sticking with AEM's philosophy of building independent components, you can create a component just for this HTML and use `data-sly-resource` in the template's page component (page component - template usually falls back to the page component to render the header, footer, body, etc) to include this component onto the page.

`<sly data-sly-resource="${'htmlcomp' @ resourceType='<<project>>/components/htmlcomponent'}"/>`

- Within the page component, you can create a static file with this HTML(say static-content.html) and do a `data-sly-include` in your blank-content.html file referencing the static HTML file.

`<sly data-sly-include="static-content.html" data-sly-unwrap/>`

- Or, if this is a use case where the complete markup needs to be authored, you'll have follow what @ronnyfm has mentioned in the comment and read this as property from the authoring dialog, using appropriate display contexts. Check [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/htl/using/expression-language.html) for the available display contexts you can use with sightly.